# Style of header gone wild: colors do not change

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, headers

I have a Word document and I'm very happy with the number format (`x.x.x.`) which is applied automatically with the level of the headers.

Since my document is about to get finished content-wise, I tried to apply some CI/CD by using colors. This is where it goes wild. I expected the colors of the numbers to change with the color of the text, but that's not the case:

[image: Screenshot of Word paragraph coloring]

How do I make sure that the numbers have the same font, size and color as the heading?

#### Version information

This is Word 2016, the document is in DOCX format. I am using styles and just a few of them (in fact I minimized the number of styles from ~40 to ~15). The document may have been an old DOC file. I didn't create it from scratch.

Comment: Hallo :) Have you tried to remove the numbers and add them again after your color change.?

Comment: Try to show paragraph marks and other hidden symbols. Is the paragraph mark the same colour as the text? If no change it and let us know what happens

Comment: Check that specific font colours aren't set in the outline numbering dialog for your styles.

Comment: @Leun4m: that kinda works, but resets all other properties such as indentation, tabs, etc. I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad: it was indeed possible to change the color of the ¶ for heading level 2 and 3, but it's not possible for heading level 1. Updating the question ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a comment by [@cybernetic.nomad](https://superuser.com/users/874295/cybernetic-nomad), I have shown the hidden signs and changed the color of the pilcrow sign (¶). Like that, it was possible to fix the coloring of heading level 2 and 3:

[image: Screenshot after changing pilcrow sign]

However, was still broken for heading level 1.

I then looked up the outline numbering dialog, as suggested by [@Tanya](https://superuser.com/users/535106/tanya). Interestingly, this property can only be changed via the context menu of the numbering and not via the style sheet options:

[image: Context menu of the numbering]

Although it was possible to change the color there, it did not restore the behavior described by [@cybernetic.nomad](https://superuser.com/users/874295/cybernetic-nomad), even if the color is set to *Automatic* - which was simply black.

I therefore followed the advice of [@Leun4m](https://superuser.com/users/873323/leun4m), which was to remove the number of the heading and then re-add it. This also changed some other paragraph settings such as indentation and tabs, but I could fix those.

Thanks for all the comments. Combining them lead to this solution.